# Configuring Jekyll for github PROJECT pages

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll, github-pages

I am at my wits end here. I've been trying to look at all other example github project pages I could find and even the blogs but none exhibit the problems I am getting. First, I am trying to create a project page for my repo. I did this by following the usual tutorials, creating a gh-pages branch in my project repo and pushing.

I managed to do these and template my files. I even managed to use HAML and SASS(they still both get converted to html/css and that's what I push to the repo so no problem there). I just think that I am configuring my jekyll wrong. First, I don't see any configurations in other people's pages that use baseurl or url on config.yml.

The problem with mine is when looping through my posts:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

It always generates the href as `href="/post-title"`

my `_config.yml` btw only has this:

```
permalink: /exercises/:title
```

The problem with this when I click the link, it always points to http://corroded.github.com/exercises/title-here when it should actually be http://corroded.github.com/projectname/exercises/title-here

I have actually tried hard coding the path by doing:

`<a href="http://corroded.github.com{{ post.url }}">` and this works. It goes to the post BUT it shows it as plain text and not as the generated html. I know I am missing something very simple here but I can't seem to find it and I've been wrestling with this the whole weekend.

Oh and I forgot to add: doing this in my localhost, I can access everything at:

`http://localhost:4000/` and clicking on links will get me to `http://localhost:4000/exercises/title-here` and IT WORKS. So I have a pretty good guess that it has something to do with the configuration.

Comment: Did you try changing the my_config.yml line: permalink: /exercises/:title to permalink: /projectname/exercises/:title  ?  I know nothing about GitHub pages, but that does seem to be an obvious (too obvious?) thing to try.

Comment: It is a bit too obvious yeah but that only then applies to posts. When I create a link to say, the about page, it still references /about which goes to the http://corroded.github.com root. Not to mention I also had to hardcode that path for my css and js files when all the other examples showed only "/css/stylesheet.css"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you have a slash at the front of your permalink, it means that all URLs should be relative to the site root. This is the reason that it's going to `http://corroded.github.com/exercises/title-here` instead of `http://corroded.github.com/projectname/exercises/title-here`. Try it without the first slash:

```
permalink: exercises/:title
```

The same thing goes for any URLs you create with HTML. If you have:

```
<a href="/about">
```

it will always go to the root of the domain (e.g. `http://corroded.github.com/about`). If you're project is called 'projectname', you can use HTML like

```
<a href="/projectname/about">
```

to link directly to pages (e.g. `http://corroded.github.com/projectname/about`).

Of course, you can also use [relative URLs](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html) (i.e. URLs without a leading slash) as well. You just have to be aware of where you are in the directory tree.

Comment: P.S. another helpful thing would be to remove the "permalink" from your config all together. That will let you see how everything behaves in its default mode and possibly give you a better understanding of what's going on.

Comment: ive actually tried removing the permalink and like i said, it looks like in all those research i forgot the most basic part: removing that forward slash. I kept thinking I *needed* to put the forward slash and just had to set the baseurl and forgot all about removing the forward slash. I thank you for pointing this out for me. Thanks thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I found that adding the project name to the beginning of the permalink generates an additional subfolder in the site's output (as expected) and doesn't really solve the problem. I posted a different workaround in my answer below.

Answer (score 29):

EDIT: This answer has been added to the Jekyll documentation at http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/.

---

I finally figured out the trick, if you're looking for a solution with the standard URL for GitHub Pages (`username.github.io/project-name/`). Here's what to do:

In `_config.yml`, set the `baseurl` option to `/project-name` -- note the leading slash and the **absence** of a trailing slash.

Now you'll need to change the way you do links in your templates and posts, in the following two ways:

When referencing JS or CSS files, do it like this: `{{ site.baseurl }}/path/to/css.css` -- note the slash immediately following the variable (just before "path").

When doing permalinks or internal links, do it like this: `{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}` -- note that there is **no** slash between the two variables.

Finally, if you'd like to preview your site before committing/deploying using `jekyll serve`, be sure to pass an **empty string** to the `--baseurl` option, so that you can view everything at `localhost:4000` normally (without `/project-name` getting in there to muck everything up): `jekyll serve --baseurl ''`

This way you can preview your site locally from the site root on localhost, but when GitHub generates your pages from the gh-pages branch all the URLs will start with `/project-name` and resolve properly.

More conversation about this problem on [issue #332](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/332).

Comment: Why hasn't this been selected as the correct answer yet?