# Setting up a GitHub Pages project page. Page is up but images and main.css are not loading

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages, static-site

Hello People of Stack Overflow,

First time setting up a project page on GitHub pages.  I'm thinking I probably missed something very simple, but I have tried everything I could find, also hoping that even though this question has a high probability of being a bit idiotic that the formatting is pretty good.

### The story so far...

Hosting a static site on GitHub pages.  It's a project page based on a working repository.  I created a   `gh-pages` branch and pushed to this branch.  That branch is now set to default and all the files are up on the [repo](https://github.com/ed42311/blackfootCarvings)  I have looked at several questions on stack overflow that are very similar to the problem I am having but they don't seem to be quite the same.

The page is loading [here](http://ed42311.github.io/blackfootCarvings/)
but neither the images or the CSS formatting is loading.  The page was built with html, css and bootstrap.

### Questions that are very like the problem:

1. This seems the closest: static resources not loading (rep < 10)
2. Maybe I need to address the root file somehow in the `_config.yml`?  Like in this question: github pages not building (rep < 10)
3. Thinking the answer lies here: in the jekyll docs (rep < 10)

### Avenues explored:

- Created `.nojykell` file in the `root` folder, this seemed to be the best option as I don't actaully need jykell.
- As another possible route, Created `config.yml` file

  - with `keep_files: [img, app.js, main.css];`
  - and then `include: [img, app.js, main.css];`
  - also added `highlighter: rouge;` in the 1st line, per a build error.
- Jykell gave me an H10 error at one point and I installed `kramdown`, although that did not do anything, got the same error.  This seems like an unnecessary step because I'm not using jekyll, just need a spot to serve the files already created in the interwebs.
- Updated ruby
- Removed ../ in front of files on the .html pages

### Other things you might need to know:

```
File structure:
    - root
      - img
      - .nojykell (empty)
      - app.js
      - index.html
      - artist.html
      - gallery.html
      - main.css
```

Let me know if you have any suggestions and thanks.  :)

Comment: This question is what lead me to the config.yml file:  [configuring jykell for github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585916/configuring-jekyll-for-github-project-pages?rq=1)

Comment: Figured it out, it was something very simple:  I had the path wrong on the CSS and img folder.  All good now.  The simple things, the simple things.  Althought the .nojykell file might have helped.  Did not test both in isolation.  I did start a new github page and went through step by step.  did not need a .nojykell file for that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to see you figured it out.

For future reference, a .nojykell wouldn't have solved the problem:

> It is now possible to completely bypass Jekyll processing on GitHub Pages by creating a file named .nojekyll in the root of your pages repo and pushing it to GitHub. **This should only be necessary if your site uses files or directories that start with underscores** since Jekyll considers these to be special resources and does not copy them to the final site.

https://github.com/blog/572-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages